# Who can develop payment processor for Bank of America Merchant Services

Tags: payment-processor

Would anyone be able to develop a payment processor for the latest CiviCRM version to work with the Bank of America Merchant Services? Can you provide a quote? We're using Joomla but I believe most/all of the payment processors are CMS-agnostic.
(Sorry if this is not the forum to ask this question - happy to take it elsewhere ;-)
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can commission an extension, using the [Core-Team](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) or a [Partner/Contributor](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors). I suggest you set up a issue in the issue tracker first to see if the Core Team can give you an estimate.

You should also look at the other payment processor extensions, the folks who wrote them are most likely to be able do another, they should also be rewarded for their previously contributed code, by getting new work.

Resource on how to create a [Payment Processor Extension](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Example+of+creating+a+payment+processor+extension)

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that Bank of America uses Payeezy Gateway, which in the past was called First Data / Global. First Data / Global is listed on the supported processors. See:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors%20

It also appears that someone has used First Data /Global as a Payment Processor. See:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=18448.15

--H

Comment: thank you for the suggestion - I'll look into this; hopefully this payment processor can do recurring payments; the overview table in the Wiki says otherwise but the table could be outdated

Comment: @MtnPavlas Did you ever test this First Data processor with Payeezy?